# awk or sed command to start each column of file from desired locations or Byte Position

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a source file format like below containing 15 columns and so many rows:

```
23.5 31.5 5.00 255   0 255 2 1 sal unknown sa time sps meter ms
25.5 32.5 6.00   0 255   0 2 2 sal unknown sa time sps meter ms
```

I convert it into desired format using following awk command:

```
awk '{printf " %-12s %-13s %-8s%3s %3s %3s %2s %-2s %-47s %-20s %-5s %-11s %-39s %-19s %-6s \n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15 }' source.fault_data > target_fmt.dat
```

Is there any short command of converting it or padding between 15 columns?

Desired format:

```
Col. No.   Col. should be between these positions 
1                   1   12
2                   13  24
3                   25  36
4                   37  39
5                   41  43
6                   45  47
7                   49  50
8                   51  52
9                   53  102
10                  103 122
11                  123 127
12                  128 139
13                  140 179
14                  180 199
15                  200 205
```

Comment: what is your **desired format** ?

Comment: Your input data is very unclear, can you please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/287912/edit) and post it again ?

Comment: See **`man column`**.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I believe you want:

- to have 1 file with 3 rows, describing each column: number, start-pos, end-pos
- and to then use that formating to display another file's content

Here is a first attempt. Note that I assume things:

- the `formattingfile` is well defined as you showed, ie:

  - the number of cols increase,
  - col. No are described in order with none missing
  - and there is a first "title" line)
- and the `filetodisplay` has NO title line.

Here is an awk program to attempt to do this:

```
 awk ' BEGIN {lastendcol=0;}
      ( NR == FNR) && ( FNR == 1 )  { next ;}
      ( NR == FNR)  { formatstring=formatstring "%-"($3-lastendcol)"s" ;
                      lastendcol=$3;
                      next ;}

          { printf formatstring"\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15 ;}
    '  formattingfile  filetodisplay
```

The first pass (NR==FNR) will read "formattingfile", ignoring the first (title) line, to create the "formatstring" formatting variable.

The second pass (NR>FNR) will then display each lines of 'filetodisplay' using "formatstring\n".

of course, here, the 2 files are:

file "filetodisplay" :

```
23.5 31.5 5.00 255   0 255 2 1 sal unknown sa time sps meter ms
25.5 32.5 6.00   0 255   0 2 2 sal unknown sa time sps meter ms
etc ....
```

file "formattingfile" :

```
Col. No.   Col. should be between these positions 
1                   1   12
2                   13  24
3                   25  36
4                   37  39
5                   41  43
6                   45  47
7                   49  50
8                   51  52
9                   53  102
10                  103 122
11                  123 127
12                  128 139
13                  140 179
14                  180 199
15                  200 205
```

Comment: note : change to `formatstring=formatstring "%"($3-lastendcol)"s"` if you prefer the things to be right-aligned.

Comment: And you could have a 4th column in the formattingfile describing if you want it to be left or right aligned... simple to add, simple to integrate in the above script (change formatting according to $4 value)